# How to find all preprocessor dependencies of a specific code

Tags: c, preprocessor

Suppose there is a C/C++ header file with over ten million lines. There are lots of `#ifdef` and `#endif` statements beyond counting. What's the most efficient way to find an arbitrary line's all preprocessor dependencies? In other words, how to find all preprocessor definitions that are required to let the compiler include or ignore a block of codes that contains such line?

For example, we have the following code:

```
#ifdef A
#if defined(B)
#ifdef C
#else
#define X 1
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

In order to let the compiler include `#define X 1`, how do I know that I should define `A` and `B` but not `C` in preprocessor without manually reading the code? Or is there an efficient method to manually find all dependencies?

Comment: You will need to write a specialized preprocessor for that. I doubt you will find any off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: Read the documentation? It should really have that information.

Comment: `gcc -E` will give you the resulting output after pre-processing.  That's not exactly a solution, but I'd say it's 1 step beyond "manually reading the code"

Comment: @Jason are you sure if it is much easier? https://godbolt.org/z/hq4eazovc

Comment: Is you have 10e6 lines headers I do not believe that they are not documemented.

Comment: @0___________ I mean... My editor doesn't mind searching the output thousands of lines.  If you need to *know* the answer, making my editor figure it out would be easier than manually keeping track of multiple states.

Comment: @Jason How will that help? That will show the code *after* lines have been conditionally included, but they want to know what macros they have to define to include what they want.

Comment: @Barmar Could you not use that to verify? I don't think he'd define X for fun.  He plans on using it.

Comment: @Jason He could use it to verify it if used the right defines. So are you suggesting that he just use trial and error with different `-D` options until the output contains `#define X 1`?

Comment: @Barmar Dude, I never said it was a solution.  Just thought that may be easier than manually trying to decipher a bunch of `#ifdef` blocks.

Comment: @Jason I don't even see how it's a part of a solution. But this whole question seems misguided. You don't usually go from wanting `X  == 1` to the options you set. The documentation should explain all the options you can set, and `#define X 1` is just part of the implementation of those options.

Comment: @Barmar Agree, documentation is the real solution.  If, for whatever reason that wasn't an option, I could see using `-E` to work backwards and spit out the current values of a macro. A simple bash script could completely remove 0______'s issue of getting a butt load of output down to just what you want to see.  Just another tool in the toolbox, you know?

Comment: 1. Write something invalid at the necessary line (e.g. `7=ABCdef///;`); 2. Try to define and undef until you get error from compiler (invalid line is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

There is AFAIK no tool that can do this for you.

As mentioned in the comments, the correct solution is to reference the documentation. If this is some odd case where that is not an option, then you may be able to work backwards by printing out the values of each macro you are confused on.  Here is a bash script I just cooked up that could automate that process for you:

deref.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
  >&2 echo "usage: $0 <file> <macro name> [<macro name> ...]"
  exit 2
fi
source_file="$1"
shift

for macro in "$@"; do
  play_file="$(mktemp "$(dirname "$source_file")/XXXXXX.c")"
  cat "$source_file" > "$play_file"
  printf '\n#ifndef %s\nUNDEFINED\n#else\n%s\n#endif' "$macro" "$macro" >> "$play_file"

  printf '%s: %s\n' "$macro" "$(gcc -E "$play_file" | tail -1)"
  rm "$play_file"
done
```

usage example...

a.c:

```c
#define X 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

in shell:

```
./deref.sh a.c X Y
X: 1
Y: UNDEFINED
```